# Есть ли разница в приросте количества вопросов между буднями и выходными?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Возможно этот вопрос уже был задан, но я его не нашел на просторах `меты`. Стало интересно - есть ли различие в количестве вопросов задаваемых за день например во вторник и в субботу на `StackOverflow на русском`. Не спорю что есть такие энтузиасты которые работают круглые сутки круглый год, но я думаю что все-таки разница должны быть, вернее мне так кажется. Возможно я ошибаюсь, либо это глупый вопрос)) я не буду спорить, мне просто стало интересно. Может у кого-то есть интересующая меня информация, я буду очень благодарен за удовлетворение моего любопытства по поводу жизни этого сайта.

Comment: Проверь на [dataSE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: это там запрос нужно какой-то слать я так понимаю?)

Comment: выбираешь сайт и пишешь sql-запрос

Comment: спасибо большое) буду там спрашивать :)

Comment: там не спрашивать, а делать надо. что-то [такое](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/910952/1133831/questions-per-day-of-week), только надо ещё надо сгруппировать по неделям и вывести график. что-то с transpose, наверное.

Comment: та я понял)) я это образно сказал, я же смайлик вроде веселый прилепил))  просто я не знаю всех сайтов сети и вы, @Qwertiy, вот мне дали инструмент для нахождения ответа на свой вопрос. Спасибо

Comment: AndrewGoroshko, :)

Comment: Судя по этой теме, в середине недели больше всего активности: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/question-and-answer-activity-on-stack-exchange-interactive-and-customized-editi

Comment: Есть еще страница аналитики: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics

Comment: @Grundy, у кого как))) у вас может и есть :)

Comment: Она у всех есть ;-)

Comment: я перешел на ту ссылку что вы мне дали, но меня культурно уведомили что мне еще нужно немного подрасти))

Comment: @Grundy *"Когда Вы заработаете по крайней мере 25000 очков репутации, Вы получите право «доступ к статистике сайта» и сможете просмотреть эту страницу."*

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, так вперед же! :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я стараюсь как могу)) но такую репу за день не сделаешь)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Есть](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/913879/weekday-question-activity-for-a-stackexchange-site?SiteDbName=StackOverflow.Ru). Число вопросов в выходные примерно 80% от общего уровня.

Comment: 80% от будничного дня. (Извините просто по началу прочёл будто бы 80 % всех вопросов за неделю :3  )

Comment: @timob256 не от будничных. Делится на общее количество вопросов (за все семь дней). 100% это уровень, как будто все 7 дней в неделе одинаковое количество вопросов имеют. По ссылке есть запрос, формула проще чем словами описывать.